# Is it possible to place EditorTemplates outside the MVC web application project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc-editor-templates

Some of my `EditorTemplates` can be reusable for other solutions. Like Login, ResetPassword etc.

So, instead of place duplicate editor template in `~\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\` folder under each solution, I would love to place them in a project I can reference for all solutions.

Is it possible to use those partial views that way?

Comment: Maybe nuget package is a good way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool called [razorgenerator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) which would allow you to compile your views into a DLL which you could reference in multiple projects

Or you could always create a nuget package

Comment: Thank you for pointing to a good direction. I looked into RazorGenerator and now have a working example. Thank you so much.